# Troubleshooting 'No module named mmcv._ext' error when running mmdetection on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, openmmlab

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 5>()
3 from mmcv.runner import load_checkpoint
4
----> 5 from mmdet.apis import inference_detector, show_result_pyplot
6 from mmdet.models import build_detector
7

5 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/**init**.py in import_module(name, package)
124                 break
125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
127
128

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mmcv._ext'

---

i have install mmcv but nothing work